# Slow local area network speed

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, local-area-network, network-speed, asus

**Background:**

Currently I have the following devices on my home network:

- Router Asus RT-N16 (Latest Firmware Version:3.0.0.4.376_3754)
- HP MicroServer Proliant Gen 8 (Windows Server 2012 Essentials)
- Desktop PC (Windows 10 with wireless stick tp-link wdn3200)

**The problem:**

While the internet speed seems to be good (download on MicroServer is 11MB/s and on the desktop is ~3MB/s), the speed for accessing the MicroServer from desktop PC (wireless) starts from 500kB/s and rapidly drops to 0.

If I try to access the server while on lan, the transfer speed is ~4MB/s, which also seem slow.

If I try to access the server with my tablet I will have 300-700kB/s.

**I already tried without any luck:**

- disable TCP checksum Offload as described here: http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/2503-extremely-slow-file-transfers-network-access-4.html
- follow the steps from here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/very-slow-200kbsec-file-copy-between-win7-machines/b8736b1b-0a91-4567-ba33-215084ffc906?auth=1
- disabled the Domain member: Digitally encrypt or sign secure channel data (always) and Microsoft network server: Digitally sign communications (always) as described here: http://jrs-s.net/2013/04/15/windows-server-2012-slow-networksmbcifs-problem/

Thank you!

**Edit:**
I reinstalled windows 10 on my desktop, installed dd-wrt on router and I made a few tests with Lan Speed Test:

When wired:

```
Write Time = 1.0785168 Seconds
 Write Speed = 370.8797200 Mbps
 Read Time = 0.5220954 Seconds
 Read Speed = 766.1435440 Mbps
```

When on wireless:

```
Write Time = 84.8323133 Seconds
 Write Speed = 4.7151840 Mbps
 Read Time = 160.6903622 Seconds
 Read Speed = 2.4892560 Mbps
```

**Ping for server (wireless):**

```
Pinging mini [fe80::cdda:7e35:48e5:5e58%8] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::cdda:7e35:48e5:5e58%8: time=6ms
Reply from fe80::cdda:7e35:48e5:5e58%8: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::cdda:7e35:48e5:5e58%8: time=3ms
Reply from fe80::cdda:7e35:48e5:5e58%8: time=4ms

Ping statistics for fe80::cdda:7e35:48e5:5e58%8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 6ms, Average = 3ms
```

**I also did a test with another pc (a notebook):**

Desktop access (wireless):

```
 Write Time = 271.3696592 Seconds
 Write Speed = 1.4740080 Mbps
 Read Time = 64.2738869 Seconds
 Read Speed = 6.2233680 Mbps
```

Server access (wireless):

```
Write Time = 12.9318064 Seconds
 Write Speed = 30.9314880 Mbps
 Read Time = 11.3660599 Seconds
 Read Speed = 35.1924960 Mbps


Pinging mini [192.168.1.134] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.134: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.134: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.134: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.134: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.134:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 2ms
```

Comment: Do you have an extra computer to add into the mix, see how fast it is? Or can you try a crossover (direct link) between the desktop and the server to rule out router problems? What is the speed between the tablet and both computers? What are your ping results between machines? Can you verify you are connected at gigabit? Are there any ethernet errors, collisions? Have you tried multiple protocols?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin: I edited the question and I added more information about the network status.  It seems that the problem appear only when accessing internal network from wireless. It appears to be for all the devices. It might be a router configuration problem? Thanks!

Comment: Check your wireless link speed on the client. Make sure it's at max speed. Verify router wifi settings are correct. Try changing wireless channel on the router as there may be interference (it seems like it). You can use "Wifi Analyzer" for Android to do a wireless site survey to look for problems and to find the best channel.

Comment: Indeed it is a very crowded area (~20 networks). I installed the app and I changed the settings to: channel 13, width 40GHz and control channel upper. Sensitivity range is on default 2000. 

The speed is now much better:  

 Write Time = 18.2726977 Seconds
 Write Speed = 21.8905840 Mbps
 Read Time = 13.0594110 Seconds
 Read Speed = 30.6292560 Mbps

Do you know if I can improve it further? The wireless link speed is 54Mbps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing wireless channel on the router to avoid interference. You can use "Wifi Analyzer" for Android to do a wireless site survey to look for problems and to find the best channel. 20 wifi networks is bad, maybe too bad. Consider switching to 5.8Ghz (more channels and such) if you can't get the speeds up.

Wifi speeds in real life

http://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-is-the-actual-real-life-speed-of-wireless-374